# Cell template with filter in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I created a cell template that depends on a filter, but the filter is not processed.

The cell is defined as `{field:'status', displayName:'Status', cellTemplate: 'cell/statusCellTemplate.html'}]` where the template is

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'{{row.getProperty(col.field) || switchStatus}}')">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</button>
```

**EDIT**

```
myapp.filter('switchStatus', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return (input == 'STOPPED') ? 'STARTED' : 'STOPPED';
    };
});
```

The rendered cell is `<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="changeStatus(row.getProperty('id'),'STOPPED')">STOPPED</button>`. I expect STARTED for the second parameter.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SPfXQbq5W25SI5p2dL5B?p=preview): when clicking on STOPPED, the current status should be STARTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `data` come from? I think you meant to check if `input` is 'STOPPED' or 'STARTED' like this:

```
app.filter('switchStatus', function() {
return function(input) {
    var out = "";
    if (input == 'STOPPED') {
        out = 'STARTED';
    } else if (input == 'STARTED') {
        out = 'STOPPED';
    }
    console.log(input + " " + out);
    return out;
};
```

You could make your filter shorter by writing:

```
app.filter('switchStatus', function() {
return function(input) {
    return (input == 'STOPPED') ? 'STARTED' : 'STOPPED';
};
```

Comment: Plunker is not working for me in my browser right now, so I thought just at a glance that might be the issue but I couldn't confirm...

Comment: I used `||` in the HTML template instead of using `|`. I accept your answer because my filter was totally wrong (damn copy paste)